# Why does my background show black in thumbnail?

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a function I often use to create thumbnails and have never had problems with until now.

My src file is:  4ddice.com/img/large/000000/0400.png

My dest file is: 4ddice.com/img/thumb/000000/0400.jpg

If you look at the pictures you will see the src has a white background but the dest has a black background.  I can't figure out why it is doing it but it is happening to just about every render I try.  [Render multiple stl files on windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427315/render-multiple-stl-files-on-windows-machine) has the code I am using to create the renders.  I thought maybe my problem was because I am changing file types but changing the output to a png format does not fix(not to mention to big for thumbnail.)

here is the code I am using to make thumbnails.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '756M');
define('MAX_PROCESS_SIZE',400);  //should be a little smaller then above.

//create thumbnail
function makeThumb($src, $dest, $maxWidth, $maxHeight) {


        //get original image domentions
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($src);

    //get height if locking to max with
    $desiredHeight = floor($height * ($maxWidth / $width));

    //get width if locking to max height
    $desiredWidth = floor($width * ($maxHeight / $height));

    //chose correct values
    $newHeight=$maxHeight;
    $newWidth=$maxWidth;
    if ($desiredHeight<$maxHeight) {
        $newHeight=$desiredHeight;
    }
    if ($desiredWidth<$maxWidth) {
        $newWidth=$desiredWidth;
    }

    //see if have enough ram
    $neededRam=($newWidth*$newHeight+$width*$height)*5/1000000;
        if ($neededRam>MAX_PROCESS_SIZE) {
        return;
    }

    //read the source image
    $sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($src);

    //create a new, "virtual" image
    $virtualImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

    //copy source image at a resized size
    imagecopyresampled($virtualImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtualImage, $dest,83);

    //clear variables
    imagedestroy($sourceImage);
    imagedestroy($virtualImage);


    //don't overload the server
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: probably your `png` has a transparent background.  `jpg` can't have a transparent background.

Comment: if that is the reason wouldn't `imagepng` instead of `imagejpeg` cause a white background still?

Comment: you should fill the `$virtualImage` with white then use `imagejpg` to create a white jpg image

Comment: yep filling virtual image with white did fix the problem.  thanks @roullie